# Unable to compile Optix Kernels at runtime

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, error

I have this issue, can't render with my GPU, not even in the viewport, it says

> `Unable to compile Optix Kernels at runtime. Set OPTIX_ROOT_DIR environment variable to a directory containing the Optix SDK`

I'm using Cycles, Blender 3.5 official release, and have an RTX 3060 graphics card.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I fixed it, there is a conflict between experimental debug settings and my GPU. I simply unchecked all of these experimental debug settings and now it works good.